# setAttribute function doesn't work in live mode

Tags: google-tag-manager, live, setattribute

I am searching for an answer/solution why my JS function with get attribute() doesn't work in live mode? In GTM debug mode, everything is ok, all events based on this function are sent normally.
Thank You

```
function() {
 var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div[data-product]"))
  for (i=0; i< x.length;i++) {
  if(Number.isInteger(i/2) && Number.isInteger(i/3)) {
    x[i].setAttribute("seen-product", "");
    }
  
  }
  
  
  
  return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a variable template. In preview mode, all variables are evaluated, no matter if they are used or not. In the live version, variables are only evaluated when they are being used (in a tag, template, or trigger).

Since you do not use the variable to return any data, I suspect that you not actually use it anywhere, so it would not be evaluated (i.e. the function would not be run) in live mode.

A variable changing things instead of returning a value is called a "side effect". Variables should not have side effects (read e.g.here: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/ (half way down the page under the headline "Variables must never have side effects"). You could do this e.g. in a custom tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was the answer i needed.